# Creating class diagrams for Android Project

Tags: android, class-design

I have tried to use Netbeans to reverse engineer my Android Project but this fails as it does not show the classes.

I am using Omondo which has created them but not properly and only allows me to create an java project not Android.

Is there any useful tool out there that will create the Android project class diagrams perfectly.

Thanks

Comment: If there isn't something of Android-specific nature in your project (if you want to treat for example, the stuff generated from AIDL service descriptions specially, there may be), then a generic Java class diagram generator will do it.

In this case, this question may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120032/what-is-your-favorite-automatic-class-diagram-generator-for-eclipse.